# Flutter: best practices for persisting same widget while navigating to different screens/routes

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, widget, persistence

For the app we are making, it is required that a widget should remain active and visible while the user navigates to different screens; specifically, we need a music player widget that keeps playing music (while showing its live controls) while the user navigates to different routes, as shown in the diagram below (in the link).

[Flutter widget persisting during navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZGZw.png)

Searching around, we found some hints on how to tackle this very basic use case (some suggest using the Material App's overlay, others the bottom sheet), but it looks like there is no "official" best practice in flutter docs [or Medium linked articles] showing how to address this very general requirement.

Are we missing something? Help, suggestions and references would be really appreciated.

EDIT ---
NOTE FOR GOODWILL READERS AND HELPERS: we are quite into Flutter developments; in facts, we just deployed a full-fledged (and complex app) in the Google and Apple Stores (the "Vox Imago" app).

Nevertheless, the use case and requirement described above is not addressed in Flutter official documentation, nor in the cookbook; and a simple demo on how to achieve the desired result seems missing (?) in the extensive list of examples available on Flutter's sites.

Any suggestion for a sound approach would definitely be valuable :)

Comment: It seems like you won't be making full screen transitions. More like how a tab bar doesn't change when the tab view does change.

Comment: @TedHenry, thanks for your reply. As far as I understand Flutter's routing, when using Navigator, the pages/routes pushed on the navigator stack occupy the full size of the screen - and all widgets of the new page are redrawn from scratch. Furthermore, when a page is popped from the stack, all its widgets are destroyed.